# Python not connecting with outsourced database config

Tags: python, sql-server

The python code doesn't establish connection to SQL Server, when I outsource the connection infos in a config.ini. But however, when I hard code the connection infos, it is working.

Connection not working:

```
import pyodbc
import configparser

# INI-Datei lesen
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
server = config['SQL']['Server']
database = config['SQL']['Database']
username = config['SQL']['Username']
password = config['SQL']['Password']

# Verbindung zum SQL Server herstellen
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

# Autocommit aktivieren
cnxn.autocommit = True

# Datenbank erstellen
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE [DB Test TCPOS]')

# Tabellen erstellen
cursor.execute('USE [DB Test TCPOS 2]')

# Table 1
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE [SHOP] ([SHOP_ID] INT NOT NULL, [SHOP_NAME] NVARCHAR(50), [TIMESTAMP] DATETIME)')
# Table 2
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE [OPERATOR] ([OPERATOR_ID] INT NOT NULL, [OPERATOR_NAME] NVARCHAR(50), [TIMESTAMP] DATETIME)')

# Verbindung schließen
cnxn.close()

print('Datenbank und Tabellen erfolgreich erstellt.')
```

Ini-File:

```
[SQL]
Server = 'ZDEVKWS0148\\SQLEXPRESS'
Database = 'master'
Username = 'test_user'
Password = 'test_1'
```

Error message:

> line 13, in 
> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL >Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]SQL Server existiert nicht oder Zugriff verweigert. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBMSLPCN]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (67)')

Working code:

```
import pyodbc

# Verbindung zum SQL Server herstellen
server = 'ZDEVKWS0148\\SQLEXPRESS'
database = 'master'
username = 'test_user'
password = 'test_1'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

# Autocommit aktivieren
cnxn.autocommit = True

# Datenbank erstellen
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE [DB Test TCPOS 2]')

# Tabellen erstellen
cursor.execute('USE [DB Test TCPOS 2]')

# Table 1
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE [SHOP] ([SHOP_ID] INT NOT NULL, [SHOP_NAME] NVARCHAR(50), [TIMESTAMP] DATETIME)')
# Table 2
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE [OPERATOR] ([OPERATOR_ID] INT NOT NULL, [OPERATOR_NAME] NVARCHAR(50), [TIMESTAMP] DATETIME)')

# Verbindung schließen
cnxn.close()

print('Datenbank und Tabellen erfolgreich erstellt.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now get the error, why is wasn't working. The issue is in the config.ini.
Error causing ini-file:

```
[SQL]
Server = 'ZDEVKWS0148\\SQLEXPRESS'
Database = 'master'
Username = 'test_user'
Password = 'test_1'
```

There is a "\", which is used to escape the "\", if the code is hard-coded.

But in the ini-file, we have to remove it:

```
[SQL]
Server = 'ZDEVKWS0148\SQLEXPRESS'
Database = 'master'
Username = 'test_user'
Password = 'test_1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
pip install python-decouple
```

```py
from decouple import config
```

Comment: Still same issue with decouple library.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @claver, I adjusted my code:

```
import pyodbc
from decouple import config

# Verbindungsinformationen aus der Konfigurationsdatei lesen
server = config('Server', default='ZDEVKWS0148\\SQLEXPRESS')
database = config('Database', default='master')
username = config('Username', default='test_user')
password = config('Password', default='test_1')

print(server, database, username, password)

# Verbindung zum SQL Server herstellen
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

# Autocommit aktivieren
cnxn.autocommit = True

# Datenbank erstellen
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE [DB Test TCPOS]')

# Tabellen erstellen
cursor.execute('USE [DB Test TCPOS 2]')

# Table 1
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE [SHOP] ([SHOP_ID] INT NOT NULL, [SHOP_NAME] NVARCHAR(50), [TIMESTAMP] DATETIME)')
# Table 2
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE [OPERATOR] ([OPERATOR_ID] INT NOT NULL, [OPERATOR_NAME] NVARCHAR(50), [TIMESTAMP] DATETIME)')

# Verbindung schließen
cnxn.close()

print('Datenbank und Tabellen erfolgreich erstellt.')
```

However, my system username get used, instead of reading in the config.ini file, which is in the same folder as the script.

Answer (score 0):

If your first print statement on line 10, prints out the values, then it should be good to go.